# not been able to send a GET request using python

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am having some functions in javascript that does the string manipulations and then my backend updates that data to database.

In short, I have a url for sending data to backend, then this data is send to javascript fucntion, js does manipulation and the using ajax request I send the manipulated string to backend, which updates my database.

I am using flask framework

Here is what I have written till now

```
#this url is where I send a GET request
@app.route('/api',methods=['GET'])
def text():
  text = request.args.get('text','')
  lang = request.args.get('lang','')
  return render_template('test.html',text=text,lang=lang)
```

Now JS does the manipulation of the strings and sends a ajax GET request to following url

```
@app.route('/files/<text>',methods=['GET'])
def fi(text):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    textValue = text.encode("utf-8")
    INSERT_DB = 'INSERT INTO text (text) VALUES (%s)'
    db = connect_mysql()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(INSERT_DB,[textValue])
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
return ''
```

Now I check if the data is save to database or not in following url

```
@app.route('/test',methods=['GET'])
def test():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    db_select_last = "SELECT text FROM text order by id DESC limit 1"
    db = connect_mysql()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(db_select_last)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return (data['text'])
```

But what I face problem is when I manually hit the url from browser it updates the data. but when I send a GET request from python it doesn't. Why is this so.

Here's how I send a GET request to that url

main_url is http://fyp-searchall.rhcloud.com/

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://fyp-searchall.rhcloud.com/api?text=some body&lang=marathi'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
```

But data does not update. Where I am doing wrong ?

> I got to know that JS works only when you have browser, so what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

In requests you should pass query parameters as a dictionary, using the `params` keyword:

```
import requests
url = 'http://fyp-searchall.rhcloud.com/api'
params = {'text': 'some body', 'lang': 'marathi'}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

See the Quickstart here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/